# Import data from another source into Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

I’m trying to tie data from another product with my data inside of Adobe Analytics. 
We have Adobe Analytics javascript on our website collecting data and we use a third party tool to track how users interact with certain parts of the website. We’re trying to use the Adobe API to tie the data together.

So far we’ve gone down the path of using the Data Insertion API, but it wasn’t quite right as it’s meant to be used as a replacement for the JS, from what I can tell.

We also explored using the Data Sources API. Now the documentation for this suggests you can use a transaction ID to tie offline data with the data collected from the JS, we’ve tried this and it doesn’t match the data up. We’re now exploring using Visitor ID to tie the sessions together but we’re having problems uploading any rows with the Visitor ID column, Adobe just returns the error “Column header: ‘visitorid’ is not a valid column header”. We’ve tried several different variations of visitor id, such as “visitor_id”, “visitor-id”, “vistor id”, etc and still no luck.

The end goal is for us to be able to upload data to Adobe that will update/add eVars for already existing sessions earlier that day. How would I go about doing this? Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Edit: I managed to solve this problem by using the Adobe SAINT API. When a user arrives at the site, we push an eVar for that user with a unique ID and then the day after we use the SAINT API and the unique ID in the eVar we pushed previously to add the additional data we needed.

Comment: What is the other product you are trying to import data from? How/when/where is the data for that product collected?

Comment: I'm a developer for the product, we're trying to build a way to get data into Adobe for our client. The data is collected via JS then processed overnight. Once the data is processed we want to use the Adobe API to tie our data with the data collected by Adobe. Hope that helps @CrayonViolent.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a good idea to look back at the Data Insertion API and combine it with the visitorId approach where you tie existing/old visitorID's to new eVars and use the timestamp to "update" the dataset.

Although this is experimental, it might be worth a try.

Best regards,

Comment: Hi Stefan, I actually managed to solve this problem using the Adobe SAINT Classifications.

When a user arrives on the site we push an eVar with a unique ID and then the day after we push data to SAINT using that eVar with the additional data we want to add to that session.

Thank you for your reply anyway!